# Create valid URL From Title In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am creating URL Form My Posted Title. Here is some sample title.

#### Title Example:

```
$title = "Global Campaign Manager - (SEO and Advertising)";
$title = "Broadcast Journalist, BBC News Online (London)";
$title = "Agile Digital Project Manager/£475 - 525 pd/6 months/London";
```

Now, Here is the URL example which i expect form this title.

#### Expected URL:

```
www.example.com/global_campaign_manager_-_seo_and_advertising
www.example.com/agile_digital_project_manager475_-_525_pd6_monthslondon
www.example.com/broadcast_journalist_bbc_news_online_london
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Convert any title or text to url codeigniter has a [URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

This helper is loaded using the following code:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Now, To convert the string to proper URL. User [url_title](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#url_title)

```
$title = "Agile Digital Project Manager/£475 - 525 pd/6 months/London";
$url_title =  url_title($title, 'underscore');
```

#### Result URL

> www.example.com/agile_digital_project_manager475_-_525_pd6_monthslondon